# What is the topological characteristic of a separable metric space $X$ such that $|kX\setminus X|=\frak{c}$ for any completion $kX$ of $X$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, metric-spaces

What is the topological characteristic of a separable metric space  $X$ such that $|kX\setminus X|=\frak{c}$  for any completion $kX$ of $X$?

Comment: Note that if (CH) then $X$ is non-Polish.